# Serialize an include for JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have tried countless iterations of this to get it to work. I am trying to serialize a request that has an include in it. The string 'param' is a variable. The request looks like this:

> {"json-rpc":"2.0","method":"getThings","params":{"guId":"All"},"id":1,"version":"1.0"}

The nested guId portion is stumping me. This is in .NET 3.5 CF thus the Newtonsoft usage.

This is the closest I was able to get:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

BuildRequest jRequest = new BuildRequest
{
    JsonRpc = "2.0",
    Method = "getThings",
    Params = param,
    Id = 1,
    Version = "1.0",
};

var httpRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jRequest, Formatting.Indented);

private class ParamsP
{
    [JsonProperty("guId")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
}

private class BuildRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("json-rpc")]
    public string JsonRpc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public ParamsP Params { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting

> Cannot implicitly convert string to ParamsP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i was able to get this to work in a console project using .NET 3.5 CF feel like you might be missing something elsewhere or perhaps I am confused on the question creating an object of type `BuildRequest` and the class being called type `BuildGetPlayers`

```
public class Process
{
    private class ParamsP
    {
        [JsonProperty("guId")]
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
    }

    private class BuildGetPlayers
    {
        [JsonProperty("json-rpc")]
        public string JsonRpc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("method")]
        public string Method { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("params")]
        public ParamsP Params { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }


    BuildGetPlayers jRequest = new BuildGetPlayers
    {
        JsonRpc = "2.0",
        Method = "getThings",
        Params = new ParamsP
        {
            GroupId = "something"
        },
        Id = 1,
        Version = "1.0",
    };

    public string Get()
    {
        var httpRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jRequest, Formatting.Indented);
        return httpRequest;
        /* returns {
              "json-rpc": "2.0",
              "method": "getThings",
              "params": {
                "guId": "something"
              },
              "id": 1,
              "version": "1.0"
            }
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for and have verified it works per my needs! The BuildReuest/ BuilGetPlayers issue was a typo on my part. I have edited my example code to be correct (in case anyone else has a similar question).